# Flutter xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier (Solved)

Tags: flutter, xcode, ios-simulator

I have built a Flutter app.
Everything was working fine until I tried to launch it on a physical device. After struggling to find a solution, I changed the Xcode configuration from debug to release and I am now able to launch the app on the physical device (by running flutter run --profile).
But now, I can not succeed in launching it on the simulator.
I receive the error :

```
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
            { id:C80BB36C-4498-4641-92D8-F69090A819A9 }
```

When I plug the device and run flutter run --profile, he asks me on which profile I want to run the app:

```
[1]: iPhone de Bernard (00008110-0012642011B8801E)
[2]: iPhone 14 (C80BB36C-4498-4641-92D8-F69090A819A9)
[3]: macOS (macos)
[4]: Chrome (chrome)
```

The iPhone 14 that Flutter proposes in the profiles is the one that is not found when I try to run the app from Android Studio on the simulator for iPhone 14.

Flutter doctor :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on macOS 13.4.1 22F82 darwin-arm64, locale fr-BE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

and Xcode 14.3.1

Your help would be very appreciated !

Many thanks !

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Thanks to this thread

my problem is solved.

Briefly:

1. Open Xcode
2. Click Runner (Root)
3. Click Build Settings
4. Change "supported platforms" from Iphoneos to iOS

Comment: 2023 everything last version this trick worked for me

Comment: I had similar issues when trying to test older iOS versions like 15.5, turns out when I opened my xcode the iOS Deployment target is at 16.4 so I had to update to 15.5

Comment: works for me. if you use xcodeproj (ruby tool for modifying xcode project file), try this :   
`frameworkTarget.build_configurations.each{ |config|`  
    `config.build_settings["SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS"] = "iphonesimulator iphoneos";`  
`}`

Comment: This solution just worked for me (Dec 2023) after updating from XCode 14.2 to 15.1 & MacOS from Monterey to Sonoma (and iOS Simulator iOS 16.4 to iOS 17.2).  Physical iPhone running 16.4 was unaffected / could still be targeted for release build.

Comment: This worked for me. I had setup multiple schemes in my app. For the debug configurations of all the schemes, the platform was set to `IOS` but for all others (release, profile), it was set to `iphoneos`. Changing those to `IOS` fixed this issues.