# xcodebuild: error - Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, ios-simulator

Recently i updated my xcode to 15.0.1, now i am facing an issue with xcodebuild while trying to build my iOS app. The error message is "Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier." I have tried

1. Deleting pod file and installing it .

. Here are the details:

Xcode Version: 15.0.1
Device/Simulator ID: Iphone 13 pro max
Deployment Target: 12
Command Used: flutter run
flutter version: 3.10.5
console output:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iphone 13 pro max in debug mode...
```

Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            2.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
{ id:B22CA3A0-F0D3-49E0-80CB-9F5A693B1130 }

```
    Available destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
            { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00008103-001931E00CE0801E }
            { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
```

Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/rg/31btzj714g10q_c9d0fqb44m0000gp/T/flutter_tools.gxeem8/flutter_ios_build_temp_diroWMUbN/temporary_xcresult_bundle

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iphone 13 pro max.

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: solved this issue  by referring this  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76630256/17577372)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier (Solved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76610625/flutter-xcodebuild-error-unable-to-find-a-destination-matching-the-provided-de)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by changing the Supported Platform in Build Settings in the Xcode Runner from Iphoneos to iOS.

- Open the project in Xcode Click on Runner
- Get into the Build
- Settings Tab  Search for "Supported Platforms"
- Change the Profiles from Iphoneos to iOS

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjOBm.jpg)

Comment: that worked for me